# Pinch gesture recognizer in uwp

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, gesture-recognition, pinch

I am developing a UWP application, in which i want to use pinch gesture.

On pinch gesture i want find what controls are there in that two pinch points.

I want to drag two elements at a same time in pinch action.

Its kind of grouping . I just want to drag two elements and once the elements get closer i merge the content of both and create a new item.
For example

[image]

I have this 4 grid view items, i want to drag two of them at a same pinch action, then once they get closer i want to merge the content.

Example: text+text2

Hope i explained it clearly.
I tried with manipulation events, but dont know how to find a pinch action.
Can anyone help me on this.

Thanks,
Noorul.

Comment: Why do you need the pinch action if you're actually not pinching but rather doing two move operations at the same time? Why not just move them separately and merge when close?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, How to move two elements, first we need to detect two touch points right?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen can you please give me sample for that ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of moving two together, Why don't you move first/second one on to second/first one?

**From a Users point of view:**

*On a phone:* To use Pinch Action, I need to hold my Phone with one hand and use second hand to pinch. Instead i can just use one hand to move one item and drag/drop on second item.

*On a Tablet:* You anyways need two hands but by default on a tablet, pinching is for zoom and scroll, you need to make sure this is also accounted for.

Do you want to rethink your approach? Or do you still want to go ahead in the same way?

Well, this is not exactly an answer but you understand what i am saying rite?